# How is JSONP any safer than JSON in cross-domain requests?

Tags: ajax, json, browser, cross-domain, jsonp

Why do browsers allow cross-origin JSONP requests and do not allow JSON requests?  I know that JSON requests are not allowed to prevent XSS, but I don't see how JSONP is safer than JSON.

In fact, could JSONP be even more dangerous because it is technically a script, where JSON is just a text string?

Answer (score 3):

**JSONP is not safer.** It's a workaround/loophole/hack to get past the same origin policy.

[CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cors/info) is the safer alternative to JSONP.

Comment: Why do browsers block JSON requests, when developers can always just use JSONP instead (which is no safer)?  What is the point of allowing one but not the other?

Comment: Developers **can't** always use JSONP. The server must support it.

Comment: So, browsers allow JSONP (and not JSON) because **less** web APIs support JSONP?  Is this the reason?

Comment: It's not that browsers "allow" JSONP. A browser can't distinguish between JSONP and a `<script>` tag whose `src` attribute references an arbitrary domain, because there is no distinction. Browsers "allow" JSONP as much as they "allow" external scripts.

Comment: I am aware of that ("allow" is just a concise way of saying it).  If a browser permits JSONP, then allowing JSON as well will not make a big security difference, right?

Answer (score 0):

Because cross-domain JSON is blocked, sensitive data can be transmitted using JSON, rather than JSONP. This prevents XSS.  Additionally, a server should not send sensitive data using JSONP.  Thus, sending data using JSON protects it from unauthorized observation.  JSON is safer in this sense.